# Why can't my web app load this script?

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, phpstorm, src

Using PhpStorm, I ran index.html in the browser (Chrome). It finds the CSS file referenced, but throws a 404 error when trying to find `main.js`. The file was generated by `gulp` and it is there. The file permissions seem correct as well (664). Any idea what's going on?

I also typed the URL to the `index.html` directly in Chrome and have the same issue so it's not PhpStorm's web server. The CSS is loading because I can see the bootstrap-like navbar that I coded in the `body`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico">
    <title>Mobile Web App</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            padding-top: 70px;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/libs/bootswatch-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <base href="/">
</head>
<body>
    ...

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/main.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Checked DevTools and it's fetching  the CSS file at `http://localhost:63342/app-folder/assets/libs/bootswatch-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` but the JS file at `http://localhost:63342/assets/libs/bootswatch-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`. That seems to be the issue but I'm not certain how to fix it.

Comment: You are using PhpStorm's own simple built in web server. Either use your own proper Apache/whatever or you will have to make some slight changes in configuration, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32990633/783119 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/30084552/783119

Comment: Got it, see my answer for how I got it working. I will change the base back to `/` when I'm on an actual server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I got it working.

- When I tell PhpStorm to open `index.html` in Chrome it launches at `localhost:XXXX/app-folder/index.html` where `app-folder` is just the project folder in PhpStorm. It basically launches it's own built-in web server which is probably better than accessing the file directly in the browser.
- I can then simply retype it as `localhost:XXXX/app-folder/` and it will work (notice the trailing slash).
- Also, I had to set the `base` as `/app-folder/` and left it at the bottom of `<head>`

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Read @Juan Mendes answer for the correct solution. Yours, here, is a hack.

Comment: His answer didn't work for me. My solution applies when dealing with PhpStorm so it may be considered a hack. This is because PhpStorm appends `/app-folder/` after `localhost:XXXX` when using its built-in web server; therefore, that new path becomes the base. A `base` of `/` would be directing you to `localhost:XXXX` which generates a `404` if you use PhpStorm's built-in web server. I am certain a `base` with `/` will work fine in an Apache web server no matter where it is positioned since it will be running at the root of `localhost`.

Comment: @jstudios I updated my answer, it had a typo. You seem to not understand what the base tag does, you'd be better off removing it if since in your example you are not actually changing the page's base path.

Comment: Like I strongly mentioned, it is a PhpStorm issue using it's built in server. If my app was being served at the root of `localhost` I wouldn't have posted this question. But PhpStorm likes to add a sub-path instead of running it at the root. I assume this is to accommodate more running apps. If I would have ran it on an Apche server, like @LazyOne mentioned in his comment, I wouldn't have had this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You have set the `<base>` tag after you set the `<link>` to your CSS, therefore, the base is the HTML the page is being loaded from. Moreover, you are setting it to the root `/` instead of the page itself (and not adjusting your link)

Fix the base before the `<link>` tag:

```
<base href="/app-folder/index.html">
<link rel="style sheet" href="assets/libs/bootswatch-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

or use an absolute path everywhere:

```
<!-- The slash in the beginning of the URL makes it absolute from the same server -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app-folder/assets/libs/bootswatch-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Note that the first base tag I showed is unnecessary (because it sets it to the same thing it already was), you could just remove it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/libs/bootswatch-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```